# How to Update Android Activity's UI from Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `Activity` whose layout is in the file `main.xml` that contains a `TextView` with the id `my_view` and a `Button` with the id `open_alert`. Clicking on the button will open an `AlertDialog`  which is dismissed on clicking ok. Once the `AlertDialog` is cancelled i need to update the value of the `TextView` from the activity.

I am not able to update the value of `TextView` from the activity.

Comment: provide more details - error log? code that failed to work?

Comment: provide the code that you have tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to restart the activity on the OnClickListener in your Alert. If you want to pass a value into the view, just add an extra attribute in the intent and reset the value in the TextView. I have posted a rough code for reference.

```
alert.setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //create a new intent
            Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR ACTIVITY NAME");
            //add your value in the intent
            int value = //your value
            intent.putExtra("value",value );
                            //start your activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in your activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
yourTextView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("value"));
```

Don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but should work.

Comment: It will work , but we need to again finish activity and restart it, which is not that gud idea. Rather than that its better to  update UI when the button is clicked  like below: <br> Button b = (Button)findviewbyId(R.id.b1);

Answer (score 3):

Just implement `onClick` listener for positive button:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
     {
       TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
       if (text != null)
       {
         text.setText("new text");
       }
     })
  .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that the android:editable attribute is present in the XML file and set to true for the target TextView. Then, in the onClick() method you will just need to use setText().